# ¿ Multiprocesos, Hilos/threads en pyqt4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, python-2.x, pyqt4

Estoy tratando de ingresar datos en un QListWidget en pyqt4, por medio de la entrada de teclado **raw_input** estoy ingresando 5 datos pero solo quiero que en la tabla me aparezcan 3, eso ya lo tengo, pero cuando ingreso la primera ronda de datos apenas se abre la GUI con los 3 datos que quiero que aparezcan, pero no me deja volver a ingresar mas datos. Según he investigado se debe hacer por medio de **HILOS O MULTIPROCESOS**, para que ejecute la GUI y el ingreso de datos al mismo tiempo, pero la verdad no he logrado entender muy bien como es que se programan los hilos o multiprocesos, es por esto que si alguien me puede ayudar respecto a como aplicar los hilos o multiprocesos en este programa estaré muy agradecido.

A continuación dejo el código del programa "codigo_llamado" que traduce la interfaz gráfica de qtdesigner:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'llamado.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(745, 487)
        self.etiqueta_modulo_n = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.etiqueta_modulo_n.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 271, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.etiqueta_modulo_n.setFont(font)
        self.etiqueta_modulo_n.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta_modulo_n"))
        self.etiqueta_turno = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.etiqueta_turno.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 81, 21))
        self.etiqueta_turno.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta_turno"))
        self.btn_llamado = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.btn_llamado.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 20, 291, 281))
        self.btn_llamado.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("border-image: url(:/imagen_llamado.png);"))
        self.btn_llamado.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.btn_llamado.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btn_llamado"))
        self.btn_salir = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.btn_salir.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 400, 141, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.btn_salir.setFont(font)
        self.btn_salir.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btn_salir"))
        self.etiqueta_turno_actual = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.etiqueta_turno_actual.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 110, 121, 41))
        self.etiqueta_turno_actual.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta_turno_actual"))
        self.lista_turnos = QtGui.QListWidget(Dialog)
        self.lista_turnos.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 210, 351, 251))
        self.lista_turnos.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lista_turnos"))
        self.etiqueta_turno_lista = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.etiqueta_turno_lista.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 61, 21))
        self.etiqueta_turno_lista.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta_turno_lista"))
        self.etiqueta_cedula_lista = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.etiqueta_cedula_lista.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 190, 61, 21))
        self.etiqueta_cedula_lista.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta_cedula_lista"))
        self.btn_reporte_excel = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.btn_reporte_excel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(424, 380, 81, 71))
        self.btn_reporte_excel.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("border-image: url(:/icono_excel.png);"))
        self.btn_reporte_excel.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.btn_reporte_excel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btn_reporte_excel"))
        self.etiqueta_generar_reporte = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.etiqueta_generar_reporte.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 450, 111, 21))
        self.etiqueta_generar_reporte.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta_generar_reporte"))
        self.etiqueta_servicio_lista = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.etiqueta_servicio_lista.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 190, 71, 21))
        self.etiqueta_servicio_lista.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta_servicio_lista"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.etiqueta_modulo_n.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><br/></p><p align=\"center\"><br/></p></body></html>", None))
        self.etiqueta_turno.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\">TURNO:</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.btn_salir.setText(_translate("Dialog", "SALIR", None))
        self.etiqueta_turno_actual.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><br/></p></body></html>", None))
        self.etiqueta_turno_lista.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">TURNO</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.etiqueta_cedula_lista.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">CEDULA</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.etiqueta_generar_reporte.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">GENERAR REPORTE</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.etiqueta_servicio_lista.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">SERVICIO</span></p></body></html>", None))

import recursos
```

Y acá dejo el código del programa que ejecuta la GUI:

```
import sys
from codigo_llamado import *
import threading

class Llamado(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        datos = True
        while datos:

            turno = raw_input("ingrese turno : ")                             
            cedula = raw_input("ingrese cedula : ")                             
            fecha = raw_input("ingrese fecha : ")              
            hora = raw_input("ingrese hora : ")                               
            servicio = raw_input("ingrese servicio : ")               

            self.ui.lista_turnos.addItem("      "+turno+"                   "+cedula+"                  "+servicio)
            datos = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Llamado()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

A continuación muestro la forma en que recibo los datos del servidor:

```
import sys
from codigo_llamado import *
import socket    #para crear el socket y recibir los datos
import threading

# Se establece la conexion
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.1.6", 8000))

class Llamado(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        while 1:
            # Se envia turno
            turno = s.recv(1000)              
            print "Turno : ", turno
            cedula = s.recv(1000)                
            print "Cedula : ", cedula
            fecha = s.recv(1000)                
            print "Fecha : ", fecha
            hora = s.recv(1000)                
            print "Hora : ", hora
            servicio = s.recv(1000)
            print "Servicio : ", servicio

            self.ui.lista_turnos.addItem("      "+turno+"                   "+cedula+"                  "+servicio)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Llamado()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hola Andrés, bienvenido a [es.so]. El problema efectivamente es que `raw_input` es bloqueante. ¿Existe alguna razón de peso para no ingresar los datos mediante un formulario en la propia GUI? Sería mucho más simple y un procedimiento más normal que usar la consola para ingresar los datos a una interfaz gráfica.

Comment: Si, ps la verdad me gustaría hacerlo de la forma como digo con **raw_input** ya que en realidad son datos que le llegan a esta interfaz desde un servidor, y quiero que se vayan adicionando en la QlistWidget, pero ps en este ejemplo lo hice con raw_input para simular los datos que llegan del servidor.

Comment: Un servidor no envia los datos a traves de raw_input, podrias mostrar como lees los datos del servidor

Comment: ¿Si deseas añadir más datos por qué estableces datos a `False`?, pasarlo a True no es la solucion pero no entiendo porque usas ese codigo si necesitas pasar mas datos, si tu haces eso es equivalente a remover el `while datos`

Comment: Hola, pues yo había puesto el raw_input como una forma de simular los datos que llegan del servidor. Ya puse el código donde recibo los datos del servidor, he quitado lo de datos **False** de esta forma siempre va a estar esperando datos, pero la GUI no se ejecuta, creo que se debe establecer un hilo para la GUI y otro para el **while** que recibe los datos pero la verdad no se como hacer eso.